# AWS Lex chabot configuration in facebook messenger

Tags: amazon-iam

while testing the chatbot using messenger, it shows "Error: The IAM Role is not properly configured for Lex"

how to IAM in aws such that it should work using IAM role

Comment: please add the configuration or something explanatory

Answer (score 0):

For my app, the IAM role is 'AWSServiceRoleForLexBots', and it integrates with the Facebook messenger.

If you navigate to 'Security, Identity & Compliance' services on AWS console, pick IAM. Further, under 'Create individual IAM users', check the 'Access Advisor' section in the user configuration. 
If you have the Administrator access, AWS should create 'AWSServiceRoleForLexBots' automatically for your profile.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Which aws role should i use to call aws lambda?. Currently `AWSServiceRoleForLexBots` does not have permission to invoke lamda method.